# Pointer arithmetic confusion in linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

So I'm looking at a linked list with nodes setup like this

```
    struct node {
        node *next; 
        node **prev;
    };
    node *rel_list;
```

Can someone explain how the pointer operations work in the following code block (from the node creation function) especially line 5.

```
    1 node *r;
    2 r->next = rel_list;
    3 r->prev = &rel_list;
    4 if (rel_list)
    5  rel_list->prev = &r->next;
    6 rel_list = r;
```

Comment: The correct method in doubly-linked lists is to use `node*next,*prev`. The `node**prev` is strange and bound to cause problems and confusion (the idea is presumably to point to the `next` member of the `node` whose next node is the previous from `this`). However, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve and what the intention of the code block is.

Comment: Why are you using `node **prev` instead of `node *prev`.  The `prev` should point to a `node`, not to a pointer.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ linked list examples" and compare to your code.

Answer (score 1):

In most linked list implementations, the pointers point to a node, not to a pointer:

```
+------+  
| prev |  
+------+  
| data |
+------+  
| next |
+------+  

+------+          +------+          +------+  
|  0   |   +------|      |   +------|      |  
+------+   |      +------+   |      +------+  
|  A   |<--+  +-->|   B  |<--+  +-->|  C   |  
+------+      |   +------+      |   +------+  
|      |------+   |      |------+   |  0   |  
+------+          +------+          +------+
```

In your code, you are making the previous pointer point to the next *pointer* not the previous *node*.

**Edit 1: Example**

```
node * ptr_node = new node;
ptr_node->prev = nulptr;
ptr_node->next = nulptr;
// Insert at the head
ptr_node->prev = head_pointer;
ptr_node->next = head_pointer->next;
head_pointer = ptr_node;
```

Linked lists are, IMHO, better drawn (pictures) to grasp concepts.  Go through the example above and "draw" each step.